# Ubuntu install is stuck in 'updates and other software' page

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

Want to dual boot Ubuntu along side windows created partition of 600GB unallocated

Downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop and I checked the all the recommended integrity check like verifying the shasum256 etc all are working good. And for if anyone says USB error or did the flash wrong I did a flashed a few timed just to check by using Rufus and also etcher in windows and also flashed in Linux using etcher.

Used a Bootable USB of 8GB flashed Ubuntu latest version.

Got into the **grub page pressed 'e' instead of 'enter' because I have a Nvidia driver** so

**I added this in the kernel with and without quike splash apci=off or nomodeset or modprobe.blacklist=nouveau(anyone at a single time)(you know to try see which works)**.

All this did nothing the graphics didn't get lower and the screen didn't zoomed in as I read in some posts. It was normal and so

It goes into the install page few times and but other times also loads slowly after a black screen and I can only see the pointer there.

The few times it goes in the installation gets stuck in updates and other software' sometimes I would connect the internet and other times I wouldn't but everytime the install gets stuck in this.

Also the whole loading process is so slow

The system(custom build)

i3 9100F chip,
1TD HDD,
4GB Ram,
Asus Prime H310M-CS R2.0 motherboard, And Nvidia Geforce GT 710

Any suggestions

Comment: If the installer crashes then there's probably an issue with your installation media. Did you verify your download before flashing it to USB?  Are you sure that it was flashed correctly? That your USB device and USB port are 100% functional? Does the completed installation media pass integrity checks?  Please edit your question with this info and also tell us which version and flavor of Ubuntu you are trying to install.

Comment: Yes it passed it and USB port is 100% function(I just installed windows 10 in it so I'm pretty sure) and the integrity check is also perfect.

Comment: Can you try to run the installer without the option to install updates and/or without the option to install 3rd party drivers?  You can update your system after installation and install the most recent nvidia driver with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450`

Comment: Tried it but this time it won't go to next after language setting what should I do now?